# Show that $L/L'$ abelian

Tags: lie-algebras

> **Problem:** Let $L$ be a Lie algebra, denote $[L L]=L'$. Show that $L/L'$ abelian.

**My attempt:** $[x,y] = (x+L')(y+L')-(y+L')(x+L') = ((x+y)+L') - (y+x+L') = ((x+y)+L') - ((x+y)+L') = 0$

Is that enough???

Comment: Should be $$(x+L')(y+L')-(y+L')(x+L') = xy-yx + L'=L'.$$

Comment: I presume $L$ is some abstract Lie algebra. Then it doesn't make sense to multiply elements of $L/L'$ like you did.

Comment: @Wojowu  They're probably matrices in most of his examples, so multiplication is just composition.

Comment: Dzoooks By definition, $[xy]$ must be equal to zero.

Comment: @Dzoooks I suppose, but that doesn't mean this proof is valid for an abstract Lie algebras. (before anyone mentions that: I know you can take the universal enveloping algebra, but I would venture a guess OP hasn't had that covered yet.)

Comment: @Minh $L'=0+L'$ is the zero element in $L/L'$.